# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'productInfo' of null React js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react but m not understanding whats going wrong with the code and i keep getting the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property **'productInfo'** of null React js`

**productInfo value is null m i setting it proper?**

error occur this line

```
var productNode=this.state.**productInfo**.map(function(productInfos,index)    


var Content1=React.createClass({

loadProductsFromServer:function(){
    var productInfo=[
        {
            "pName":"Shrugs",
            "pId":"1",
            "pPrice":"400",
            "pImg":"http://MYLINK/images.png"
        },
        { 
            "pName":"Jewelry",
            "pId":"2",
            "pPrice":"100",
            "pImg":"http://MYLINK/images.png"
        },
        { 
            "pName":"Shoes",
            "pId":"3",
            "pPrice":"500",
            "pImg":"http://MYLINK/images.png"
        }       
    ];      
    this.setState({productInfo:productInfo});   //is it set proper                  
    },

getIntialState:function(){  
    var productInfo=[];     
    return{
        productInfo:productInfo         //is it set proper  
            }
    },

componentDidMount:function(){
     this.loadProductsFromServer();      
},  

render:function(){      
    var productNode=this.state.productInfo.map(function(productInfos,index){// here the error occurs wherein the productInfo has null data          
        return(
             <div className="conDisp">                         
                 <div className="pSet">                                                                         
                    <div className="pName">
                       {productInfos.pName}
                    </div>
                    <div className="pPrice">
                        {productInfos.pPrice}
                    </div>                
                </div>
             </div>
           );
        });     
    }   
});





ReactDOM.render(
      <Content1/>,
       document.getElementById('content')
       );
```

**productInfo value is null m i setting it proper?** in render return function

These are the scripts are been used

```
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, post React 0.13, you'll need to call getInitialState yourself in the constructor. The constructor should read:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = this.getInitialState();
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/webpack/react-starter/issues/77) for discussion of this issue.

Comment: not working i read the dicussion there it says getintialstate works with react.createclass

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    render:function(){      
     {            
            return(
                {this.state.productInfo.map((productInfos,index) => {return 
                     <div className="conDisp">                         
                         <div className="pSet">                                                                         
                            <div className="pName">
                               {productInfos.pName}
                            </div>
                            <div className="pPrice">
                                {productInfos.pPrice}
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                     </div>
             })}
           );
      }
```

Comment: {this.state.productInfo.map(productInfos,index):error unexpceted near 'this.'
      ^

Comment: try this now i forget to add '('

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: myUrl/content.js: Unexpected token (44:21)
       {            
              return(
>                 {this.state.productInfo.map((productInfos,index) => {return 
                       <div className="conDisp">                         
                          <div className="pSet">                                                                         
                               <div className="pName">

Comment: i have my code in question section thats all i have

Comment: var productNode=this.state.**productInfo**.map(function(productInfos,index)    
may be error is in this line try to remove it. you can not access the state out side the class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131546/discussion-between-hir-and-shailesh-prajapati).